# From 2-round key-exchange protocol to a public-key encryption scheme CPA-secure

Tags: key-exchange, protocol-analysis

I have to solve this exercise and I really could use some help:

Show that any 2-round key-exchange protocol (that is, where each party
sends a single message) satisfying $Definition$ $9.1$ can be converted into
a public-key encryption scheme that is CPA-secure.

$Definition$ $9.1$: 
 
A key-exchange protocol II is secure in the presence of
an eavesdropper if for every probabilistic polynomial-time adversary $A$ there exists a negligible function negl such that

$Pr [KE^{eav}_{A,\pi} (n) = 1] \le \frac{1}{2}+ negl(n)$

Comment: Hint: Look at DH and ElGamal / ECIES / DHIES.

Answer (score 1):

The methods suggested in the comments are useful in practice, but they base on some specific key exchange protocols. It's useful to proove that a public key encryption scheme can be created from any such $KE^{eav}$-secure protocol.

#### Notation

Let $\langle s_A, m_A \rangle, \langle s_B, m_B \rangle$ denote the state and transmitted message from Alice and Bob within the protocol respectively. 
Let $Prot_A(1^n) \rightarrow \langle s_A, m_A \rangle$ denote the process of Alice creating her secret state and the message to be transmitted to bob, $Prot_B(m_A) \rightarrow \langle s_B, m_B \rangle$ be the process of Bob sampling his random state and creating the message based on the random state and Alice's message. We then define the key to be $f(s_A, m_B) = k_A = k = k_B = f(s_B, m_A)$ for $f$ some predefined function.

#### Construction

Now, we create a public-key encryption scheme as follows:

\begin{align*}
    Gen&(1^n)  \\
    & \langle s_A, m_A \rangle \leftarrow Prot_A(1^n) \\
    & \langle s_k, p_k \rangle = \langle s_A, m_A \rangle \\
    & Output \space \langle s_k, p_k \rangle \\
    %
    %
    Enc_{p_k}&(m): \\
    & \langle s_b, m_b \rangle \leftarrow Prot_B(p_k) \\
    & Output \space \langle m_B, f(s_B, p_k) \oplus m \rangle \\
    %
    %
    Dec_{s_k}&(c): \\
    & \langle m_B, c' \rangle = c \\
    & k = f(s_k, m_B) \\
    & Output \space k \oplus c'
\end{align*}

#### Correctness

Since $f(s_k, m_B) = f(s_A, m_B) = f(s_B, m_A) = f(s_B, p_k)$ the correctness follows from the correctness of a one-time-pad.

#### Security

We can proceed to prove CPA-security by reduction. Assume there is an adversary $\mathcal{A'}$ which succeeds at breaking the CPA experiment for our public-key encryption scheme $\Pi'$. We construct an adversary $\mathcal{A}$ breaking the KE experiment as follows:

1. $\mathcal{A}$ receives $m_A, m_B, \hat{k}$ as input
2. $\mathcal{A}$ runs $\mathcal{A'}(1^n, m_A)$ and receives $m_0, m_1$
3. $\mathcal{A}$ samples $b \leftarrow \{0,1\}$ uniformly and computes $c = \langle m_B, m_b \oplus \hat{k} \rangle$
4. $\mathcal{A}$ runs $\mathcal{A}'(c)$ and receives $b'$
5. $\mathcal{A}$ outputs 0 iff $b = b'$

Now we have 2 cases to consider -- when $\mathcal{A}$ received the true key ($[K=\hat{k}]$) and when it received a uniformly random string ($K \neq \hat{k}]$). But in the first case, the result of the KE experiment will be 1 exactly when $\mathcal{A}'$ succeeds in the CPA experiment. In the other scenario, since $\mathcal{A}$ samples b uniformly, the result of the experiment will be 1 when $b = b'$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Hence:

$Pr[KE^{eav}_{\mathcal{A}, \Pi}(1^n) = 1] = \frac{1}{2}Pr[KE^{eav}_{\mathcal{A}, \Pi}(1^n) = 1 | K = \hat{k}] + \frac{1}{2}Pr[KE^{eav}_{\mathcal{A}, \Pi}(1^n) = 1 | K \neq \hat{k}] =
\frac{1}{2}(Pr[Pubk^{CPA}_{\mathcal{A}', \Pi'}(1^n) = 1] + \frac{1}{2}) = 
\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{p(n)} + \frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2p(n)}$

This contradicts $\Pi$ being $KE^{eav}$-secure, hence $\mathcal{A}'$ cannot exist and $\Pi'$ is CPA-secure.

Comment: The notation of tuples is somewhat inconsistent in your construction. Also, the symbols your looking for are probably "\langle"=$\langle$ and "\rangle"=$\rangle$ instead of $<$ and $>$.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I fixed the notation.